# Add hindi font in CK editor

Tags: ckeditor

I want to add hindi fonts in ck editor. I added following css in content.css of ckeditor.

```
font-family: 'kruti_dev_010regular';
src: url('fonts/kruti_dev_010-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/kruti_dev_010-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/kruti_dev_010-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('fonts/kruti_dev_010-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/kruti_dev_010-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/kruti_dev_010-webfont.svg#kruti_dev_010regular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

And i added the following line into config.js of ck editor:

```
config.font_names = 'Kruti Dev 010/"krutidev_010";' + config.font_names;
```

I generate the fonts and css by using this link:

[Webfont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

And i added all generated fonts into fonts/ folder in my ckeditor app.

Now kurti dev fonts is appearing in font style drop down but hindi font is not applying by this. Where is the problem in my code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hindi fonts are not working in CKEditor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545879/hindi-fonts-are-not-working-in-ckeditor)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Download hindi font Kruti010 fonts.[here](http://indiatyping.com/index.php/download/95-hindi-font-krutidev)

   Add this in Config.js of CkEditor ......

   ```
   config.font_names = 'Hindi/Kruti;' + config.font_names;
   ```

   add hindi fonts in ck editor's langs folder.

   ```
   ckeditor/lang/Kruti/k010.ttf
   ```

   add css in content.css  of ckeditor.

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'Kruti';
       src: url('lang/Kruti/k010.eot');
       src: local("Hindi"), url("lang/Kruti/k010.ttf") format("truetype");
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       }
   ```

   check your path properly.