# Hindi content is not showing in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

Ckeditor is not showing hindi content properly when fetch from database. My ckeditor code is as below:

[image]

Please find attached image as output.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Show the relevant program code.

Comment: what is the Collation of the field in database table?is it utf8_general_ci?post some code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24545879/8638699